# WOL on Debian 10 doesn't work (works on windows!)

Tags: debian, ethernet, realtek, wake-on-lan

There are too many similar question in Stack without answer! so please read this **[LINK](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)** first.

---

Problem is:
Wol was working with windows but doesn't under Debian; seems it's known problem according to above link in **[this section](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Wake-on-LAN_supported_but_just_won.27t_wake_up)**.
there is a *driver download link* (on second link above) that doesn't work, so:

1. anyone can help on which driver I should download?
2. what's this link trying to achieve? replacing driver?

---

**System configuration:**

> Motherboard: `Gigabyte GA-G41MT-D3`
> Green Lan: `disabled`
> ACPI Suspend type: `S1(POS)`
> PME Event Wake Up: `enabled`
> ErP Support: `disabled`
> Onboard Lan Boot ROM: `disabled`

---

**ethtool enp3s0 output:**

> Supported ports: `[ TP MII ]`
> Supported link modes:   `10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full`
> `100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full`
> `1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full`
> Supported pause frame use: `Symetric Receive-only`
> Supports auto-negotiation: `Yes`
> Supported FEC modes: `Not reported`
> Advertised link modes:  `10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full`
> `100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full`
> `1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full`
> Advertised pause frame use: `Symetric Receive-only`
> Advertised auto-negotiation: `Yes`
> Advertised FEC modes: `Not reported`
> Link partner advertised link modes:  `10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full`
> `100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full`
> `1000baseT/Full`
> Link partner advertised pause frame use:  `Symetric Receive-only`
> Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: `Yes`
> Link partner advertised FEC modes: `Not reported`
> Speed: `1000Mb/s`
> Duplex: `Full`
> Port: `MII`
> PHYAD: `0`
> Transceiver: `internal`
> Auto-negotiation: `on`
> Supports Wake-on: `pumbg`
> Wake-on: `g`
> Current message level: `0x00000033 (51)`
> `drv probe ifdown ifup`
> Link detected: `yes`

Comment: What network card are you using and what driver?  This information can be found with `lspci -v`.

Comment: It could be that WOL works when the PC is in **suspended** state, but not in **shutdown** state. Have you tried both ? And [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/134841/1050528) may help too. Note: chipset should be Realtek RTL8111D/E on motherboard: Gigabyte GA-G41MT-D3: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G41MT-D3-rev-13/sp#sp. Specs from Realtek [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8111g) and a few tips [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Realtek) as well

Comment: @Anonymous I knew it's been a long, im away and so sorry!! by your helps plus some tricks and researches it became possible! IF YOU POST IT, I CAN ACCEPT AS ANSWER.

Comment: This is great. I would then suggest that you answer your own question and mark it solved.  Because I only gave you some clues but I don't know what you exactly did in your particular case. It would be useful if you could document the steps you followed, then the question will be closed along with a clear solution for the benefit of others.

Comment: @Anonymous Such a **generous** advice! TNQ, I will.